# VSTO 2010 Runtime on Windows XP SP3

Tags: vsto, windows-xp, dependency-walker, apimonitor

I developed an Excel VSTO add-in in Visual Studio 2010. It works fine on different combinations of Windows 7+ and Excel 2007+, but fails to load on Windows XP and Excel 2007 with a non-informative "A runtime error occurred during the loading of the COM Add-In" message. `VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS=0` and `VSTO_LOGALERTS=1` produce no data.

After debugging with API Monitor and Dependency Walker, I found the following. In order to load the add-in, Excel loads `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOLoader.dll`. This library imports [`GetFileVersionInfoEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from `C:\Windows\System32\Version.dll`, which is available only starting with Vista. So loading of my add-in DLL is not even attempted, since the process fails very early during loading of VSTO Runtime.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Am I missing some dependency? Here is what I have installed so far:

- .NET 2.0 SP2
- .NET 3.5 SP1
- .NET 4.0
- Office SP3
- VSTO 2010 Runtime from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48217
- PIAs from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18346

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too ran into this **bothersome** issue.

For those of us still supporting clients on XP, you can still use the previous release **VSTO 10.0.50903** without this issue.

While Microsoft has hid the old download detail pages, you can still find the prior release at this very deep link:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/0/0/C001737F-822B-48C2-8F6A-CDE13B4B9E9C/vstor_redist.exe

Funny note, System requirements for the new **VSTO 10.0.60724** version *still* note "Windows XP (x86) with Service Pack 3 - all editions except Starter Edition" is still a Supported Operating System. As you point out, this is sadly incorrect.

Comment: Thanks! Downgrading VSTO to 10.0.50903 made my add-in work.